# Can't get at Content-Type header using Express 4 Router

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, http-headers

I'm trying to return different content, based on the `Content-Type` header in the request: plain text, or JSON object. In Express 3.x, I used the `req.accepted('application/json')` to find out if the user asked for JSON. but `req.accepted()` has been deprecated in 4.x.

I tried `req.is()` - returned `undefined`, and `req.accepts()` - useless. Finally, I resorted to:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    var serverTime = (new Date()).toLocaleString();
    if(req.get('Content-Type').indexOf('json') !== -1) {
        res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.send({serverTime: serverTime});
    }
    else {
        res.send('serverTime: ' + serverTime);
    }
});
```

This works great on localhost (tested with CURL), but once I deployed to Heroku, I'm getting:

```
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined at 
    Object.router.get.res.set.Content-Type [as handle]
```

How can I get the header type in Express 4, and handle properly? Is Heroku stripping th header somehow? Or maybe it's those new middlewares?

**Update:** I just verified that using CURL works every time, using a browser yields `undefined`  for `req.get('Content-Type')` on both local and Heroku - so this is not a Heroku issue. Still, I need the header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking `Content-Type` on a `GET` request does not make sense. The `Content-Type` header defines the type data in the request body, and a `GET` request has no body. `req.is` also checks this, so it is also useless in this case.

You should be setting the `Accept` header to `application/json` from the client making the `GET` and using `req.accepts('json')` on the server to verify that the client has indicated that it supports JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was mixing the headers (and testing with CURL allowed me to add a Content-Type even to a GET, even though it didn't belong there). However, regular GETs accept */* unless other wise specified - meaning that chacking for `req.accepts('application/json')` will return true. How to uniquely test for a SPECIFIED `application/json`?

Comment: Ok, ended up using `if(!req.accepts('*/*') && req.accepts('application/json')) {`  - thanks for setting m on the right track!

Comment: No need to check for `*/*`, `req.accepts('json')` will work just fine.